# Is "This hat is small and has a nice color" grammatically wrong?

Tags: parallelism

[This site](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/using-parallel-verbs) says:

> When two or more verbs have the same subject the verbs must be
>   parallel. Parallel verbs mean the verbs used in a sentence should all
>   be the same tense
>
> *Yesterday Donna watched a movie, cleaned her apartment and was making
>   lunch.*:
>
> The sentence is not correct because **watched** and **cleaned** are the simple
>   past tense, but **was making** is the past progressive. The verbs are not
>   parallel.
>
> The correct sentence should be:
>
> *Yesterday Donna watched a movie, cleaned her apartment and made lunch.*

Is "*This hat is small and has a nice color*" grammatically wrong?

I am not sure "*is*" & "*has*" belong to the same tense?

Comment: The rule might make sense as matter of style, but as a grammatical rule it is bogus. *This shirt fits me perfectly and was on sale for only $5.*  In your sentence about Donna, the word **yesterday** governs the tenses. *Yesterday Donna watched a movie, cleaned her apartment, and was going to give her dog a bath, but decided against it.*

Comment: So it was in the beginning, is now and ever shall be: we mustn't change tense without a good reason, but good reasons exist in abundance.  If they didn't, there'd also be no reason *to have* tense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find anything wrong with the sentence (This hat is small and has a nice color) Both the verbs are in present tense. 'That hat was small and has a nice color' would be grammatically wrong as 'was' is the past tense and 'has' is the present tense.